# How to set variable with the result of findstr

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file which searches for pdf files and finds how many pages they have and loop all pages.

I wrote the following. I can find the files, I can even find the pagecounts with a tool named pdftk. The results is as below.

```
C:\Users\test\Documents\fishes\Fish_1.pdf
NumberOfPages: 5
```

How can I set a variable which has the value of `5`?

```
@ECHO off
for /R %%i IN (*.pdf) DO (

ECHO %%i
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" %%i dump_data | findstr NumberOfPages

set pagecount = findstr NumberOfPages ???

FOR /L %%j IN (1,1,%pagecount%) DO (
    ECHO "page " + %%j
)

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already 90% there. Use the FOR /F command to process the results of a command. Type `HELP FOR` from the command prompt for more info.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in (
  '"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" %%i dump_data ^| findstr NumberOfPages'
) do set numberOfPages=%%A
```